# Topic Modelling - Assign human readable labels to topic

Tags: label, topic-modeling

I want to assign human readable labels to the results of my topic modelling.
Is there any software library or data set that I can use that takes these key words as an input, and returns a title to describe the topic.

Example:

Input:   `["Church","Priest","God","Prayer"]`

Output:  `"Religion"`

Note: I want automatic label creation - Not manual like others have asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P11-1154) by Jey Han Lau. He describes how to automatically generate labels using different sources and features.

> We generate a set of label candidates
>   from the top-ranking topic terms, titles of Wikipedia
>   articles containing the top-ranking topic terms, and
>   also a filtered set of sub-phrases extracted from the
>   Wikipedia article titles. We rank the label candidates
>   using a combination of association measures, lexical
>   features and an Information Retrieval feature.